# Does keeping a robo-call telemarketing caller on the line waste the marketers resources?

Tags: marketing

A habit I've gotten into, when I have time, is intentionally keeping the line open when I get automated or heavily scripted telemarketing calls. I got into this a long time ago because I had been told or read that it ties up their lines and keeps them from bothering someone else for the 2 minutes the sales pitch takes versus just hanging up. Given how long I've been doing this I felt it wise to review the habit.

This claim is made by sources [like this one](http://no-more-calls.com/how-to-waste-a-telemarketers-time/) which makes the claim that:

> If everyone spent 2 minutes talking to every telemarketer that called
>   them, telemarketing as an industry would go out of business in a few
>   days.

It obviously wastes some resources. I am skeptical of the amount or cost of those resources. Further the source seems centered around human-driven calls as opposed to pre-recorded or AVR (automatic-voice-recognition) based calls.

There is even enough desire to do this that one company is offering a [paid service](http://www.jollyrogertelco.com/) to keep marketers on the line with a robot.

Does this habit have any meaningful impact in tying up the resources of a marketer?

Phones don't really have "lines" anymore. I'm certainly not tying up a physical landline. Do modern VoIP systems have any constraints on the number of outbound calls made at one time?

Comment: We have a rule that only widely-held beliefs are in scope for this site (or at least, claims made by notable people and organisations that are widely seen).  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: [Here](http://no-more-calls.com/how-to-waste-a-telemarketers-time/) is a source you can use to get this question reopened.

Comment: Usually, call-center customers do not get flat-rates. So you do at least drive up costs. Also any IP-system has limitations (Bandwidth, computing time) if you want to make more calls => cost goes up.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that source focuses strictly on the cost in wages, which makes voip vs physical lines irrelevant.Looking at wages only, it seems intuitive that keeping someone on the line longer lowers their calls/hour, thus lowering the overall sales/profit.

Comment: You can offload this onto a bot if you like: http://www.jollyrogertelco.com/

Comment: @Oddthinking some commenters have helped and I added their references to my question. Is this sufficient to get you to reconsider your close votes?

Comment: @Freitheit: No, it actually confirms that the claim is confused. The quoted claim is about tying up the time of human agents from an [outbound call center](http://searchcrm.techtarget.com/definition/outbound-call-center). The headline is about a [robocaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocall) or [outbound IVR](http://www.genesys.com/definitions/what-is-outbound-ivr). The claims are very different.